# ConcurrentQueue one element is taken by two threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, interlocked, interlocked-increment

I want two threads to be working with one queue. First thread should be called every 2 seconds, and the second thread - every 3 seconds. Both threads should start at the same time. I have  a problem when accessing first element of the queue. Both threads take the element with index 0. Sometimes it happens with other elements of the queue, not only with the first element.
I have such an output on Console:

- Item 0 processed by 1 Time: 3:27:8
- Item 0 processed by 2 Time: 3:27:8
- Item 2 processed by 1 Time: 3:27:10
- Item 3 processed by 2 Time: 3:27:11
- Item 4 processed by 1 Time: 3:27:12

and so on..

Here is the code I use:

```
    ConcurrentQueue<int> sharedQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        sharedQueue.Enqueue(i);
    }


    int itemCount= 0;


    Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
    {
        // create the new task
        tasks[i] = new Task(() =>
        {
            while (sharedQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                // define a variable for the dequeue requests
                int queueElement;
                // take an item from the queue
                bool gotElement = sharedQueue.TryDequeue(out queueElement);
                // increment the count of items processed
                if (gotElement)
                {
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                    Console.WriteLine("Item " + itemCount + "processed by " 
                        + Task.CurrentId + " Time: " + dt.Hour + ":" + dt.Minute + ":" + dt.Second);
                    Interlocked.Increment(ref itemCount);   
               if (Task.CurrentId == 1) 
                    Thread.Sleep(2000);
                else 
                    Thread.Sleep(3000);                       
                }

            }
        });
        // start the new task
        tasks[i].Start();


    }
    // wait for the tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    // report on the number of items processed
    Console.WriteLine("Items processed: {0}", itemCount);
    // wait for input before exiting
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to finish");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the following line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Item " + itemCount + "processed by " ...);
```

With this line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Item " + queueElement + "processed by " ...);
```

The problem you are seeing is likely due to the tasks executing `Console.WriteLine` at nearly the same time and both are seeing the same value of `itemCount` because they have interleaved in such a manner that the `Interlocked.Increment` calls have not happened yet. It probably makes more sense to print out `queueElement` anyway since it is more meaningful.

Comment: +1. More to the point, `itemCount` is not meaningful at all because Thread A could get the first item, Thread B gets the second, but then Thread B increments `itemCount` first. So although Thread B actually got item 2, it would report that it got item 1.

Comment: @JimMischel: Ha...yeah, I didn't even think about that!

Answer (score 4):

See [Brian Gideon's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648148/56778) regarding your `itemCount` problem.

You might consider rewriting your code to use [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) rather than `ConcurrentQueue<T>`. It's much easier to work with. `BlockingCollection` is a wrapper for concurrent collections. In its default configuration, the backing store is a `ConcurrentQueue`. So you get the same concurrent queue functionality but with a much nicer interface.

```
BlockingCollection<int> sharedQueue = new BlockingCollection<int>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sharedQueue.Add(i);
}

// CompleteAdding marks the queue as "complete for adding,"
// meaning that no more items will be added.
sharedQueue.CompleteAdding();

int itemCount= 0;

Task[] tasks = new Task[2];
for (int i = 0; i < tasks.Length; i++)
{
    // create the new task
    tasks[i] = new Task(() =>
    {
        foreach (var queueElement in sharedQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine("Item " + itemCount + "processed by " 
                + Task.CurrentId + " Time: " + dt.Hour + ":" + dt.Minute + ":" + dt.Second);
            Interlocked.Increment(ref itemCount);   
            if (Task.CurrentId == 1) 
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            else 
                Thread.Sleep(3000);                       
        }
    });

    // start the new task
    tasks[i].Start();
}
```

[GetConsumingEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) returns an enumerator that will get the next item from the queue until the queue is empty. It also handles cancellation well, which is a bit more difficult with `ConcurrentQueue`.

In general, any time you think of using `ConcurrentQueue<T>`, you probably want `BlockingCollection<T>`.